# Mockito mock() and recording of invocation

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Mockito in order to do some mocks/testing. My scenario is simple : I have a class mocked using `mock()` and I'm invoking this class (indirectly) for a large number of times (i.e. ~100k)

Mockito seems to hold some data for every invocation, and so I run out of memory at a certain point.

I'd like to tell mockito not to hold any data (I don't intend to call `verify()`, etc, I just don't care, for this specific tests, what reaches to that mock). I don't want to create new mocks with every invocation.

Comment: I'm not sure that the holding data is from Mockito, can you post your code please, also have you used JProfile or similar to check where the information is being stored?

Comment: In that situation I would probably write my own stub object outside of Mockito, using an anonymous inner class or static nested class. According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17437660/1426891), it may not be possible to reset the mock without resetting the stubbing.

Comment: I'm sure it was mockito; I have replaced my mocks with dummy implementations of mine, and no more OutOfMemory.
Code is as simple as can be :
Foo x = mock(Foo.class); for (int i=0; i<1mil; i++) {x.someMethod();}

Comment: @Jeff Bowman : Thanks; I know I can write my own implementation, but this frustrates me a bit, because then what would be the point of using a mocking framework, if I need to do something as simple as this.

Comment: @Andrei Mockito is a great tool, but all tools have limitations. One of Mockito's limitations is that it uses a decent amount of memory per-invocation, so it doesn't scale to millions of runs well; luckily that's a rare case for the unit tests for which it's designed. The problem isn't simplicity, but scale; by analogy you're claiming "what would be the point of having an eyeglass screwdriver, if it can't do something as simple as driving wood screws".

Comment: In fairness, I'd hardly call a test with ~100k invocations "simple".

Comment: I agree Mockito is a great tool (I actually used it extensively and I'm really fond of it). Yes, I consider ~100k invocations a "simple" test just because the testing code itself has 10 lines in total. Maybe it just doesn't fall under "unit tests" category, but rather integration tests.
Thanks !

Comment: This issue is covered in detail at https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=84

Comment: Use Mockito.reset(yourMockInstance) method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.reset(mock)`, just be aware that after you call it, your mock will forget all stubbing as well as all interactions, so you would need to set it up again. [Mockito's documentation on the method](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) has these usage instructions:

```
List mock = mock(List.class);
when(mock.size()).thenReturn(10);
mock.add(1);

reset(mock);
//at this point the mock forgot any interactions & stubbing
```

They do also discourage use of this method, like the comments on your question do. Usually it means you could refactor your test to be more focused:

> Instead of reset() please consider writing simple, small and focused test methods over lengthy, over-specified tests. First potential code smell is reset() in the middle of the test method. This probably means you're testing too much. Follow the whisper of your test methods: "Please keep us small & focused on single behavior". There are several threads about it on mockito mailing list.